# Very slow when order by id, but fast when order by timestamp, id

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, primary-key

I encountered a very puzzling optimization case. I'm no SQL expert but still this case seems to defy my understanding of clustered key principles.

I have the below table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chargeQuote` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `features` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sequenceIndex` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `previousSeqId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `refOrderId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `refSeqId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `seqId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `userId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `fee` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `filledAmount` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `makerFeeRate` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `takerFeeRate` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `triggerOn` decimal(36,18) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_STATUS` (`status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_USERID_SYMBOL_STATUS_TYPE` (`userId`,`symbol`,`status`,`type`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7937243 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

This is a big table. 100 million rows. It's already sharded by `createdAt`, so 100 million = 1 month worth of orders.

I have a below slow query. The query is pretty straight-forward:

```
select id,chargeQuote,features,sequenceIndex,createdAt,previousSeqId,refOrderId,refSeqId,seqId,updatedAt,userId,version,amount,fee,filledAmount,makerFeeRate,price,takerFeeRate,triggerOn,source,`status`,symbol,type
from orders where 1=1
and userId=100000
and createdAt >= '1567775174000' and createdAt <= '1567947974000'
and symbol in ( 'BTC_USDT' )
and status in ( 'FULLY_FILLED' , 'PARTIAL_CANCELLED' , 'FULLY_CANCELLED' )
and type in ( 'BUY_LIMIT' , 'BUY_MARKET' , 'SELL_LIMIT' , 'SELL_MARKET' )
order by id desc limit 0,20;
```

This query takes 24 seconds. The number of rows that satisfy `userId=100000` is very little, around 100. And the number of rows that satisfy this entire where clause is 0.

But when I did a small tweak, that is, I changed the order by clause:

```
order by id desc limit 0,20; -- before
order by createdAt desc, id desc limit 0,20; -- after
```

It became very fast, 0.03 seconds.

I can see it made a big difference in MySQL engine because `explain` gives that, before the change it was using `key: PRIMARY` and after it finally uses `key: IDX_USERID_SYMBOL_STATUS_TYPE`, as expected, and I guess therefore very fast. Here's the explain plan:

```
select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
SIMPLE  orders      index   IDX_STATUS,IDX_USERID_SYMBOL_STATUS_TYPE    PRIMARY 8       20360   0.02    Using where
SIMPLE  orders      range   IDX_STATUS,IDX_USERID_SYMBOL_STATUS_TYPE    IDX_USERID_SYMBOL_STATUS_TYPE   542     26220   11.11   Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

So what gives? Actually I was very surprised by the fact that it was not naturally sorted by id (which is the PRIMARY KEY). Isn't this the clustered key in MySQL? And why it chose to not to use index when it's sorted by id?

I'm very puzzled because a more demanding query (sort by 2 conditions) is super fast but a more lenient query is slow.

And no, I tried `ANALYZE TABLE orders;` and nothing happened.

Comment: Does `ANALYZE TABLE` change this?

Comment: What do you mean by "sharded by `createdAt`"? Do you e.g. add a new table every month/delete old data? Then your statistics might be off (e.g. MySQL might have a different idea about how many rows per user you have), and, as Luuk proposed, reanalyzing might fix it. Please add the explain plan.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)

Comment: @Solarflare yes that's the case. But the sharding hasn't happened in this fresh new instance of MySQL yet. But your comment on stats gives me a hint: one additional info is that the variation of orders by users is very big: some user has 10 mil orders. Most users have very little

Comment: I will add explain plan

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAIN` before changing the `ORDER BY`.  Maybe with that, we can explain "why".

Comment: For your second try, you probably wanted DESC:  `order by createdAt DESC, id desc`

Comment: @RickJames the first row in the EXPLAIN result is before changing `ORDER BY`. And the second row is for after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has two alternative query plans for queries with ORDER BY ... LIMIT n:

1. Read all qualifying rows, sort them, and pick the n top rows.
2. Read the rows in sorted order and stop when n qualifying rows have been found.

In order to decide which is the better option, the optimizer needs to estimate the filtering effect of your WHERE condition. This is not straight-forward, especially for columns that are not indexed, or for columns where values are correlated. In your case, the MySQL optimizer evidently thinks that the second strategy is the best.  Inn other words, it does not see that the WHERE clause will not be satisfied by any rows, but thinks that 2% of the rows will satisfy the WHERE clause, and that it will be able to find 20 rows by only scanning part of the table backwards in PRIMARY key order.

How the filtering effect of a WHERE clause is estimated varies quite a bit between 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0.  If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can try to create histograms for the columns involved to see if that can improve the estimation.  If not, I think your only option is to use a FORCE INDEX hint to make the optimizer choose the desired index.

For your fast query, the second strategy is not an option since there is no index on createdAt that can be used to avoid sorting.

*Update:*
Reading Rick's answer, I realized that an index on only `userId` should speed up your `ORDER BY id` query.  In such an index, the entries for a given `userId` will be sorted on primary key.  Hence, using this index will both make it possible to only access the rows of the requested `userId`, and access the rows in the requested sort order (by `id`).

Comment: Am I correct that it can, in some situations, mix 1 and 2?  See my Answer for how that might happen.

Comment: @RickJames I think what your answer suggest, is what index to create for strategy 2 to be efficient when sorting on createdAt, id.  Strategy 1 is to create the entire result, then sort it.  By creating the index you avoid the sorting, so this will be strategy 2.  By including userId in the index, you also reduces the amount of data that needs to be read.  This is a very good idea that can also be applied to original query. I will update my answer on this point.

Comment: This is a super detailed and convincing answer. Thanks!

I guess in my case, when `LIMIT` was added, MySQL starts to read rows one by one, starting from the row with largest `id`, in the hope that it might soon find 20 rows and thus return. Alas the truth is that there's no row satisfying the `WHERE`. It ended up scanning the whole table

Comment: @Boyang - That's the gamble.  The Optimizer has no reliable way to pick between choice 1 and choice 2.

Answer (score 1):

The main filters works well with cardinality estimator. When order by uses limit, this is automatically another filter, as data needs to be filter further. This may redirect cardinality estimator to prone to inaccurate estimation which eventually result a poor plan to be selected. In order to prove this, run the 24sec query without the limit clause. It should also respond at 0.3 as your trick.
In order to solve this, if you have a standard very good performance just with the main filters, select this first, and filter at later 2nd time where the result set will be significantly smaller than the whole table. Use something like:

select * from (select ...main select statement)
order by x limit by y

...or...
insert into temp select ...main select statement
select from temp order by x limit by y

Comment: You are right! After removing `LIMIT`, the query DOES use the index and is as fast. Thanks for shedding light on this

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
and userId=100000
and createdAt >= '1567775174000' and createdAt <= '1567947974000'
and ...    -- I am not making use of the other items
order by createdAt DESC, id desc   -- I am assuming this change
limit 0,20;
```

I would try

```
INDEX(userId, createdAt, id)  -- in this order
```

1. `userId` is tested by `=` is first, thereby narrows down the part of the index to look at.
2. Leave out the columns tested by `IN`.  If there are multiple values in a `IN`, we can't make use of step 4.
3. `createdAt` filters further by range.
4. `createdAt` and `id` are compared in the *same* direction (`DESC`).  (Yes, I know 8.0 has an improvement, but I don't think you wanted (ASC, DESC)).

Comment: 2 - Is that the case? Last I remember MySQL will be smart and, for IN queries, use index several times (that is split it as if it's multiple queries with `=`)
4 - You are absolutely right. Edited

Comment: @Boyang - But then it cannot apply the index to the `ORDER BY .. LIMIT ..`, which is possibly more productive.  That is, _if_ there are only `=` compares and optionally a range comparison on the `ORDER BY` column, then it can move on to the `ORDER BY`.  If it gets busy with some other range or multi-valued `IN`, then things the rows in the index are no longer in order.  So it would have to do a "filesort".